# jquery get all input fields to and array

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input boxes

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label><input type="text" title="1"></label>
 </li>
 <li>
    <label><input type="text" title="2"></label></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
 $('.editdets').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();
    var inp =$('ul>li>label>input:title').toArray()
    alert(inp);
 });
```

I want to get all title(s) from input fields and store them into array.

I can't use `attr().toArray` as it then says to array is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map()`, return [`HTMLElement.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/title)

```js
 var inp = $.map($("ul>li>label>input"), function(input) {
   return input.title
 });
 console.log(inp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="text" title="1">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="text" title="2">
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var itemlist = [];
$("input").each(function (a, b) {                
     itemlist.push($(b).attr("title"));
     console.log(itemlist);
});
```